# how to know which div is rendered and how to get the child elements of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[plz checkout the link](https://codepen.io/himabindukalla/pen/zXGxxB?editors=0100)

Here I have div with 6 child div's. Now my requirement is to know which side of the cube is displayed.

I have tried to find that the div is in the view port or not. If it is in the view port, then I am getting child elements of that div by using childElementCount. But ended with no answer.

```js
_roll() {
  var cube = this._root.getElementById('cube');
  var min = 1;
  var max = 24;
  var xRand = this._getRandom(max, min);
  var yRand = this._getRandom(max, min);
  cube.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateX(' + xRand + 'deg) rotateY(' + yRand + 'deg)';
  cube.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + xRand + 'deg) rotateY(' + yRand + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%
}

#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 6s;
}

#cube:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cube div {
  background: #aa0000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 48px 0px;
}

#cube .front {
  transform: translateZ(75px);
}

#cube .back {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#cube .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#cube .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#cube .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

#cube .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}

.dot {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.front .dot1 {
  top: 62px;
  left: 62px;
}

.back .dot1 {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}

.back .dot2 {
  top: 112px;
  left: 108px;
}

.right .dot1 {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}

.right .dot2 {
  top: 62px;
  left: 62px;
}

.right .dot3 {
  top: 112px;
  left: 108px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="cube" onclick="${e => this._roll()}">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="dot dot1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="dot dot1"></span>
      <span class="dot dot2"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="dot dot1"></span>
      <span class="dot dot2"></span>
      <span class="dot dot3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Start by correcting the syntax error in your JavaScript.

Comment: get the length of class(`.dot`) as `$('.container .dot').length()` or `document.querySelectorAll('.container .dot').length;`

Comment: Fix your question too, it's not pretty clear what you want.

Comment: @Sinto, I do not think using jquery is an option since the OP has tagged only javascript.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt then the OP can use the non-query part of Sinto's comment.

Comment: actually my js function is working fine. this function is only for rolling the dice.after rolling, i have to get the face value.

Comment: @Sinto, yeah I can but jquery is uncalled for and if the OP tries to implement that without including jquery script, obviously the code is going to break.

Comment: I understant your concern. But I could not edit the comment now.

Comment: if there is a solution in jquery please keep it. i will get managed to convert the code into js.

Comment: You can't have duplicated ids, not only is it invalid -- it's going to cripple your JavaScript. Change all `id="dot"` to `class="dot"`... actually just remove all `id="dot"` the code that you copied already has `class="dot"`.

Comment: ok. i have already removed.

Comment: Don't bother counting dots. Give each "face" a `data-dot` attribute and assign each a value of 1 to 6. Also give each "face" a class that they can share maybe...`class="face"`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is complicated to give you a strait forward answer since at the begining you sould roll to a spcific face and not to a degree.

Anyway, the only thing I can think of out of the box is to reset the degree back to base every click. and then you can create a const array that holds the position (deg) of every face, and then you get random as a key for the array.

```
const arr = {'front' : [1260, 90], 'back' : [1350, 720] ... } ;
var rand = getRandFace();//'front' or 'back' ...;
//then you apply the values from `arr[rand]`.
cube.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + arr[rand][0] + 'deg) rotateY(' + arr[rand][1]+ 'deg)';
```

on the next click you rest back the cube degree (to 1, now), but you should do the position reset without animation. 
Sorry. but I think you need to rewrite it.

There is a way to acheive it as you did this, but its very complicated.

Comment: thanks @Avi fatal, my requirement is fulfilled by your approach.